# How to manually add ssh key to keychain?

Tags: terminal, password, ssh, keychain

In the past year I've been using `dsa` keys to access several remote machines. On one of these machine, dsa keys have been deprecated so I simply switched to `rsa`. In doing so it seems that my key is not stored anymore in the `keychain`, so everytime I restart my computer I get asked for the passphrase.

To add the key I tried this:

```
ssh-add -k .ssh/id_rsa
```

But also this:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-add -k .ssh/id_rsa
```

It works until the next reboot.
If I open the keychain and look there for ssh I see the dsa key, the old one.
Which would be the correct way to add the new one?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a new item in the keychain app by pressing the small + Button at the bottom. It should look like this.

[image]

Comment: it didn't actually work. it keeps asking me for the passphrase

Comment: Have you checked 1. That you entered the correct passphrase into keychain 2. The path to the key is correct